# I don't give it as a string but python treats it as a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer, typeerror

```
 class book():
    def __init__(self,name,author,page,type):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.page = page
        self.type = type
        print("Book information")
    def __len__(self):
        return self.page
xxx = book("Of mice and men","John Steinbeck",293,"Roman")
print(len(xxx))
```

this code is true.but if i write `return "Page : {} ".format(self.page)` instead of `return self.page`,i meet error.Why?

Error = TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgEyg.png)

Comment: The docs state a `__len__` method should return an integer. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__

Comment: As an aside, `type` is a bad name for a variable as there is already a built-in `type`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works just fine, but the code in the image returns a string not an int as @Axe319 pointed out.

If you wanted the function to print that text you could just add a print statement in the `__len__()` method, i.e.

```
 class book():
    def __init__(self,name,author,page,type):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.page = page
        self.type = type
        print("Book information")
    def __len__(self):
        print(f"Page {self.page}")
        return self.page

xxx = book("Of mice and men","John Steinbeck",293,"Roman")
print(len(xxx))
```

Though that is not great. You could also add a property (`book_length_str`) that would return the string you want, i.e.

```
 class book():
    def __init__(self,name,author,page,type):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.page = page
        self.type = type
        print("Book information")

    def __len__(self):
        print(f"Page {self.page}")
        return self.page
    
    @property
    def book_length_str(self):
       return f"Page {self.page}"
    
xxx = book("Of mice and men","John Steinbeck",293,"Roman")
print(xxx.book_length_str)
```